# How can we extract startup UWP applications information?

Tags: c++, uwp, windows-10, regedit

I am using C++ code base to develop a forensic tool. The requirement is to display all the startup applications. However, UWP apps which are enabled to run at startup, are not found in RegEdit at "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" or any other paths which have startup applications info.

If I have to write a code to extract Startup applications like Cortana,Skype,Spotify etc (UWP apps) from registry or windows folders, how do I do it?
Is there any path where UWP startup applications are stored?

Note: I know that all the installed applications are stored in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ but out of them, how to recognize which are startup enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Windows.Management.Deployment` APIs.

1. Enumerate installed packages via `PackageManager.FindPackagesForUserWithPackageType`
2. Use `GetPackageApplicationIds`
3. Use `StartupTask.GetAsync` to get a `StartupTask` using the application ID.

See [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/PackageManagerFindPackagesWithPackageTypes) which is provided as both C++ and C#.

Comment: I've tried this and the app needs to be run as an administrator.